# If statement based on click

Tags: jquery, click, if-statement

I am trying to check to see if the html of a div element contains "Your entered code is incorrect." However I need to check if this is true after a click occurs. Here is what I have thus far:

```
if($('.wpcf7-form-control').click()) {
    if($('.wpcf7-not-valid-tip-no-ajax').html() == 'Your entered code is incorrect.'){
        $('.sidebar-demo').delay(800).click();
    }
    else{
        $('#formalert').delay(800).click();
    }
}
```

This creates and infinite loops of clicking, I'm pretty sure I'm forming the statement incorrectly but am stuck. Thoughts?

Comment: To attract more answers, you should add a tag corresponding to the language or tools you are using. You can do that by [editing your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11726193/edit) and adding tags at the bottom of the edit page.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass a handler function into the click event. Also, jquery-ify the form once and then use it. Querying the DOM for the same element is expensive and redundant.

```
    - Edits: Use "===" it tests for value and type, does not use coercion.

    - Edits: Declare your variables with only one var statement.

    - Edits: This is purely a stylistic preference but I use a "$" when I jQuery select an element to remind myself that it has been jQueryified.


 var $wpcformControl = $('.wpcf7-form-control'),
 $wpcf7Ajax = $('.wpcf7-not-valid-tip-no-ajax'),
 $sideBarDemo = $('.sidebar-demo'),
 $formAlert = $('#formalert');

 $wpcformControl.click(function() {
     if($wpcf7Ajax.val() === 'Your entered code is incorrect.') {
         $sideBarDemo.delay(800).click();
     }
     else{
         $formAlert.delay(800).click();
     }
 });
```

Comment: +1 Good catch. @user1324700: with your current code you're literally causing a click on the control, not testing if it was clicked. It's essentially *always* true.

Comment: I see what you are trying to do here but its not working. Maybe I should preface my questions by mentioning that this form is in a popup.

Comment: Why don't you tell me which errors you are receiving. If you are using Chrome click Ctrl+Shift+J to open your console.

Comment: No errors, your code is good and it should be working. I think it isnt working because its searching for "Your entered code is incorrect." in a popup window that isnt visible all the time. Best way to show you what I mean is to check out the page on production (note that its missing the captcha element that would actually display this error):http://www.vecna.com/solutions/infection-surveillance click on "Request Demo"

Comment: You do realize I am checking for "Your entered code is incorrect" because that is the code you specified in your example. If you want me to check for something else you should update your example.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('.wpcf7-form-control').click(function() {

    if($('.wpcf7-not-valid-tip-no-ajax').text() == 'Your entered code is incorrect.') {
        $('.sidebar-demo').delay(800).click();
    }
    else{
        $('#formalert').delay(800).click();
    }

});
```

Not sure if you can force click on a page element though like you are trying to do here:

```
$('#formalert').delay(800).click();
```

and here:

```
$('.sidebar-demo').delay(800).click();
```

I remember this being possible a year ago but I think newer browsers restrict this for security reasons now.

Comment: The content im searching for is in a form that exists in a popup on the screen which is why I'm using delays on the clicks. Your code doesnt seem to be working either, I played with the delays too.

Comment: @user1324700 Does the pop up bring in this content via ajax or is it always on the page just hidden until the pop up is displayed. If the latter then it shouldn't matter whether the content is in a popup or not. If the former then you need to change `.click(function() { // });` with `.live('click', function() { // })`. Also maybe it doesn't work because of the force click issue I mentioned in my answer. To make sure thats the issue & nothing else, try replacing those 2 lines with alerts like `alert('text found')` and `alert('text not found')` and tell me if the alerts are responding correctly.

Comment: @user1324700 instead of `$('.sidebar-demo').delay(800).click()` try `$('.sidebar-demo').delay(800).trigger('click')`. Make the same change to the other.